# Pedir confirmación para ir al link de un enlaces

Tags: html, jquery, jsp, bootstrap-5

Tengo una página jsp que tiene un enlace con forma de botón (usando bootstrap) que enlaza con un controlador.
Lo que quiero es que al hacer click en el enlace, me aparezca una ventana de confirmación, y al aceptar, vaya al link del enlace.
La cosa es que pretendo hacerlo sin picar código JavaScript.
He intentado hacerlo con un modal de bootstrap pero no funciona.

¿Se os ocurre alguna forma de hacerlo? ¿Hay algun plugin de jquery que me permita hacerlo sin codificar nada?

Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Un modal de Bootstrap sirve, otra cosa es que no hayas conseguido hacerlo funcionar. Si hubieras puesto el código que has intentado, quizá podríamos ayudarte. Ah, también tienes la opción fácil que es usar confirm().

Answer (score 1):

El abrir un modal es perfectamente posible con Bootstrap, y lo hace de forma automática. Lo que sí que tendrás que hacer, es añadir un evento al botón para que se dirija a a nueva pestaña. A continuación, te paso un ejemplo de cómo sería y el código de js para redireccionar la página.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#acceptUser").on('click',function(evt){   
     $(window).attr('location','https://stackoverflow.com')
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal">
  Open Modal
</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel">Título</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      ¿Desea continuar?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="acceptUser"  class="btn btn-primary">Sí</button>
        <button type="button" id="dismissUser"  class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```